# IE not executing a form with action a servlet and a complicated input submit

Tags: forms, internet-explorer, post, input, submit

I really need some help:( 
I have an issue on IE (7-8-9), I cannot execute the submit which works perfectly on Chrome and Firefox, the servlet works too, I've tested it.
To be more specific. if you click on the input, shown as link-styled, on IE nothing happens, I have also tryed the trick to execute the submit with a form without the action and method fields, but nothing happens, it never really "fires" the submit.

The input submit I'm using is:

```
<span style="color:#355D8A;">
<!--SUBMIT-->
<input onMouseOut="this.style.textDecoration='none'; this.style.cursor='auto'" style="background-color:transparent;color:#355D8A;
width:120px; margin-left:0px;" onMouseOver="this.style.textDecoration='underline'; this.style.cursor='pointer'"  
type="submit" style="background-color:transparent;" name="cancel1" value="Cancel something"
id="cancel1" /></span >
```

and the form is:

```
<form action="some_servlet_call" method="post" name="form_name" id="form_id">
```

If you need to see more code here there is:

```
[...]
<body>
<form action="some_servlet_call" method="post" name="form_name" id="form_id">
<!-- PAGINA -->
<input type="hidden" name="pagina" value="pagina_value" id="pagina" />  
[...]                                                                                
<!--COUNTER-->                       
<input type="hidden" name="contatore" value="2" id="contatore" />                                                  
<!--CODE-->                        
<input type="hidden" name="code_value1" value="code_value" id="code_value1" />
[...]
<!--CODICE-->
<input type="hidden" name="codice1" id="codice1" value="2" />
[...]
<table width="100%" align="center" >
<tr >
<td> 
<!-- SELECT  -->
<select id="select1" class="class_example" onChange="myUpdateSelect(1);">                                                   
<option id="1option1" selected="selected">Option1</option>                                      
<option id="2option1">Option2</option>
<option id="3option1">Option3</option>
<option id="4option1">Option4</option>
</select>
<!--SELECT ASSOCIATED INPUT-->
<input name="selectHidden1" id="selectHidden1" type="hidden" value="Option1" />                                  
</td>
<td>
<!--EMAIL-->
<input id="email1" class="email_input_class" type="text" name="email1"
onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'test@mail.com';}" style="width:190px;"
onfocus="if (this.value == 'test@mail.com') {this.value = '';}" value="test@mail.com" />   
</td>
[...]
<td> 
<span style="color:#355D8A;">
<!--SUBMIT-->
<input onMouseOut="this.style.textDecoration='none'; this.style.cursor='auto'" style="background-color:transparent;color:#355D8A;
width:120px; margin-left:0px;" onMouseOver="this.style.textDecoration='underline'; this.style.cursor='pointer'"  
type="submit" style="background-color:transparent;" name="cancel1" value="Cancel something"
id="cancel1" /></span >
</td>
[...]
```

the javascript function is:

```
function myUpdateSelect(counter){
  var selectId = "select"+counter;
  var selectHiddenId = "selectHidden"+counter;
  var selectChanged = document.getElementById(selectId);
  var selectHiddenChanged = document.getElementById(selectHiddenId);

  var idOption = selectChanged.options[selectChanged.selectedIndex].id;

  var selectedOption = document.getElementById(idOption);

  for(var i=0;i<selectChanged.options.length;i++){
    selectChanged.options[i].selected = false;
  }
  selectedOption.selected = true;

  selectHiddenChanged.value = selectedOption.value;                                             
}
```

I'm sorry I don't understand how to format the code here as html...

Answer (score 0):

After many tries I've found that the form was misplaced somehow, I placed the tag deeper near the section I needed to post and IE did the job.
Still don't know why, exactly.